# Get members posts per day in percent

Tags: php

I want to calculate how many posts a member have publish per day (for example "46% posts per day"). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: depends, what system are we talking about?  Homebrew system?  is this for a shelf bought forum board?  Is this an API for facebook?  going to need a lot more to go on.

Comment: What would this be a percentage of? If I made 40 posts in a day, how do you get "posts per day percentage"?

Comment: `totalPosts/totalDays = postsPerDay`

Comment: Brad: Procent of all the posts the member have published!
Mike: The system is created by myself.
Mitch: Exacly! How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Here is a good example of demonstrating capturing the percent of a number: http://www.learningwave.com/lwonline/percent/percent_num.html

Comment: @ErikEdgren: The normal way you'd calculate any percentage: 100 * number / total_number.

Comment: What does `46% posts per day` mean?  Shouldn't that be `46 posts per day`.

Comment: Rocket: I didn't know how exactly I accomplished this so I asked you and now I know more :) Like I said, "**for example** '46% posts per day'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about,

`$postsPerDay = $totalPosts / $daysSinceRegistration;`

Comment: will it return the percentage ? im not sure

Comment: @ErikEdgren If it worked, please accept the answer (in the future), that would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Sietse: Oh. I'm truly sorry for that. Your answer is correct of course :) Many thanks once again.